# Empty Tds when Mapping Json files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, html-table

I have used `$http.get()` to get a couple of different JSON files and then called them using `$q.all()`. After making a promise I have combined them all in one big array using `.map()` function.

This is my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in full">
            <td>{{data.data.color}}</td>
            <td>{{data.data.something.brand}}</td>
            <td>{{data.data.something.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I get the output, but my table is messed up. For the first 5 table rows, I receive empty data wrapped in `ng-binding` in the first `<td>` and in the other two `<td>`s I get data. The best is if you see the image.

Image:

[image: Color Value Data]

Now, I do know that this is because of complex JSON structure I made by mapping the files and placing them into one big array, but is there anything I can do to sanitize this code?

The main file - big array is defined in `$scope.full` in `controller.app`. Please don't ask me to put the code from controller...

Comment: I am thinking that your $scope.full has some issues. Can you print your data on UI like {{full}} and check first five rows has "color" data in it. After printing you will get the idea why table is getting messed up with your full.

Comment: I can print entire json file. This happens because I have combined (mapped) two files into one array. Is there a way I can do something to erase this spacing?

Comment: while inserting your data to array you can use str.trim() and then try

Comment: The output of the table seems correct with your implementation. I wonder what you expect it to look like?

Comment: how can I make it with .map? This is the part of my controller:`.map(function(promise) {
                return promise.success(function(data) {
                    return data;
                })
            })`

Comment: @Alexander, I expect it to be in one row.

Comment: I get it. You need to merge your data. You need to loop over your arrays (brand/value) and set the matching color property

Comment: How? please write as an answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: With or without .map()?

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this, I need it as well..?

Comment: Can you put a sample of data ?... like 1 or 2 rows?... also the html output for that table?